# Safari on iOS only showing fixed elements after scroll stopped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I'm coding a "return to top" button that should be visible only when the user scrolls down my web page, and be hidden when the user scrolls up.

The rule is like this:

- if the page scrollTop is > 100px then the button is shown
- if the page scrollTop is <= 100px then the button is hidden

When running that page with Safari on iOS9 (iPad mini) the button shows **only** when the scroll animation has ended, however it hides immediately when the scroll up reach the scroll limit.

You can see a sample of the way I do it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jkwqq59a/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container 
{
    position: relative;
    height: 3000px;
    background-color: blue;    
}
.box
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;    
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function()
{
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 && !$('.box').is(':visible'))
         $('.box').show();
     else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 100 && $('.box').is(':visible'))
         $('.box').hide();
});
```

My question is: on iPad why do the button shows only AFTER scroll down is finished when it hides immediately on scroll up? How can I make it shows immediately, like it does with any web browser on my Mac?

Comment: I think this is because the event does not fire until the scroll stops. See the "browser compatibility" section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll): "In iOS UIWebViews, scroll events are not fired while scrolling is taking place; they are only fired after the scrolling has completed. See Bootstrap issue #16202. Safari and WKWebViews are not affected by this bug."

Comment: The scroll event is actually fired multiple times during scroll, I did some console.log and it logged a thousand of times during the scroll. Also the button would hide AFTER scrolling up as well, however it hides immediately when scrollTop reach 100px which means the event is fired many times.

Comment: @Voxen what browser were you using to log the scroll events?

Comment: I'm using Safari on my Mac using remote console to the iPad

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and my fix was not having a fixed position container into a fixed position container. Meaning by this that fixed elements alone work fine, but not nested.